# Set Monitoring Level to Verbose in an Azure Web Role using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I've created some custom Performance Counters in our web application deployed to an Azure Web Role. In order to be able to see the values of that Performance Counters in the dashboard, I have to go to the portal, set the Monitoring Level to Verbose, and add the new Metrics in the dashboard.

The problem is that we are creating the infrastructure by code using PowerShell, and every time we recreate the infrastructure, we lost these settings.

Can I set the Monitoring Level and the Metrics (and possibly alerts) via PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you cannot set the monitoring levels and metrics via PowerShell or the REST API. The only think you are allowed to do via REST is to create alerts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn510366.aspx

Thanks.